# Migrations ran out of gas

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

**I have unboxed pet-shop. Then inside the contracts folder, I made a file Election.sol which has the code -**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;


contract Election{
    string public candidate;
    constructor() public{
        candidate = "candidate 1"; //state var

    }   
}
```

**Then inside migrations folder, I made 2_deploy_contract.js which has the code -**

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election );
};
```

**Truffle-config.js -**

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      from:"0xCAEf077F78ce851B21524363753b4A49a4a6D503",
    },
    develop: {
      port: 8545
    }
  }
};
```

**When I do truffle migrate, I get this error.** -
truffle migrate

## Compiling your contracts...

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

## Migrations dry-run (simulation)

> Network name:    'development-fork'
>   Network id:      1
>   Block gas limit: 0x1388

## 1_initial_migration.js

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" ran out of gas (using Truffle's estimate.)
   * Block limit:  0x50e7c
   * Gas sent:     undefined
   * Try:
      + Setting a higher gas estimate multiplier for this contract
      + Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js'
      + Making your contract smaller
      + Making your contract constructor more efficient
      + Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
        private network or test client (like ganache).

```
at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Truffle v5.0.22 (core: 5.0.22)
Node v8.10.0

Comment: @shaileshMishra can you please help in this question. I am not being able to comment in the previous one.

Comment: try to set `gas` for the `transaction` using `deployer.deploy(Election, {gas: 4612388, from: "0x...."});`. The problem seems to be that the `gas limit` for the transaction is greater then the allowed `block limit`

Answer (score 1):

You can set also the `gas` amount on your `truffle-config.js`, try setting the `gas` like this one below:

```
...
networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/xxxxxxxx"),
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 4600000
    },
}
...
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get the same error @Joenel de Asis

Comment: When I run "ganache-cli", it says - command not found. And if I write this "npm install -g ganache-cli"
This comes-
/home/neha/.npm-global/bin/ganache-cli -> /home/neha/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js
/home/neha/.npm-global/lib
`-- ganache-cli@6.4.4